# How can i find latitude and longitudes from a Geo JSON file?

Tags: ios, swift, geojson

I have a Geo JSON file and i am able to read it. Now the problem is i don't know how can i find lat,lng from this json file. Here is the json file object

```
  ["division": dhaka, "city_count": 19, "geojson": <__NSArrayI       0x280fe4b00>(
   {
  "city_count" = 5;
    coordinate =     {
    features =         (
                    {
            geometry =                 {
                coordinates =                     (
                                            (
                                                    (
                            "90.35087585449219",
                            "23.87767555995429"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35293579101562",
                            "23.87783252903805"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35465240478516",
                            "23.87940220940522"
                        ),

                                                    (
                            "90.33697128295898",
                            "23.77372029600594"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33422470092773",
                            "23.77434867446102"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33353805541992",
                            "23.77670506662895"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33662796020508",
                            "23.77874723863914"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.3350830078125",
                            "23.78173189388713"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33473968505859",
                            "23.78471648062244"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33731460571289",
                            "23.78691560595149"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33851623535156",
                            "23.78958592240541"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33885955810547",
                            "23.79225618399747"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33920288085938",
                            "23.79524052908337"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33868789672852",
                            "23.79775360862461"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34109115600586",
                            "23.79916719450499"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34212112426758",
                            "23.80183725920138"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34126281738281",
                            "23.80544961231463"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33920288085938",
                            "23.80890481258195"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33817291259766",
                            "23.81204582395521"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33937454223633",
                            "23.8144015326186"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.340576171875",
                            "23.81644311221666"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33920288085938",
                            "23.81801353621191"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33576965332031",
                            "23.81864170048991"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33645629882812",
                            "23.82115432719981"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33748626708984",
                            "23.82288172984448"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33988952636719",
                            "23.82460910949492"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34160614013672",
                            "23.82617943467697"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34246444702148",
                            "23.82869191543645"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34040451049805",
                            "23.83104732195727"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33851623535156",
                            "23.83340268570913"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33885955810547",
                            "23.83638608505927"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33971786499023",
                            "23.83842731875501"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34074783325195",
                            "23.84093956227041"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33851623535156",
                            "23.84470783627317"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33645629882812",
                            "23.84706295190193"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33714294433594",
                            "23.84926102121543"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.33851623535156",
                            "23.85193005526536"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34109115600586",
                            "23.85507002494591"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34383773803711",
                            "23.85773893934751"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.34675598144531",
                            "23.86025080855958"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.3486442565918",
                            "23.86386153521903"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35036087036133",
                            "23.8665302684893"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35053253173828",
                            "23.86998384167086"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35053253173828",
                            "23.87296639892589"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35018920898438",
                            "23.87516402872517"
                        ),
                                                    (
                            "90.35087585449219",
                            "23.87767555995429"
                        )
                    )
                );
                type = Polygon;
            };
            properties =                 {
            };
            type = Feature;
        }
    );
    type = FeatureCollection;
}]
```

suppose if i try to find this  "90.35293579101562",
                            "23.87783252903805" lat lng how can fid this or how can i know this coordinate is contains in this json file.

Thanks

Comment: can you past the original json  ?

Comment: it's a huge file.. maybe i can share you from google drive

Comment: do you have any problem getting into the array of lat and longs ?

Comment: i am not sure how can i add all lat lng in a array

Comment: i mean who are you decoding this are you getting an array of objects ?

Answer (score 1):

To find out if an element existed in an array of elements you can simply use `.contains()` function,

for example if it was as simple as an array you can do this,

```
let foo =  [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,8]

if foo.contains(1) {
print("Yes it does")
}
```

However if you get an array of some custom object for example your `long & lat`,

You need to take 2 steps first

1- You have to confirm to `Equatable` protocol
  2- You have to add an extension to implement the `==` operator, then simply use the same function observe the code below.

```
struct CustomLocation: Equatable {
    var long: String
    var lat: String
}

extension CustomLocation {
    static func == (lhs: CustomLocation, rhs: CustomLocation) -> Bool {
        return lhs.long == rhs.long && lhs.lat == rhs.long
    }
}

let location1 = CustomLocation(long: "1,1", lat: "1,1") // test object
let location2 = CustomLocation(long: "2,3", lat: "2,3") // test object
let myWantedLocation = CustomLocation(long: "5,5", lat: "5,5") //the wanted object
let locations = [location1, location1, location1, location2, location2, location2, myWantedLocation] // an array of the same object include one value from my wanted object

//a check up test
if locations.contains(myWantedLocation) {
    print("Yes It Does") // prints out yes it does 
}
```